# SSH into a specific vagrant box rather than the default one

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have 3 vagrant boxes

```
vagrant box list
```

---

```
hashicorp/precise32 (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
hashicorp/precise64 (vmware_fusion, 1.1.0)
laravel/homestead   (virtualbox, 0.4.2)
```

---

when I do `vagrant up`, and `vagrant ssh`, I kept logged into `hashicorp/precise32` machine.

How do I ssh into this box `hashicorp/precise64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## vagrant ssh {hostname}

---

## Example

if you declare 3 Vms in your vagrant file.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.define "lb01" do |lb01|
    lb01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    lb01.vm.hostname = "lb01"
    lb01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.50"
  end

  config.vm.define "web01" do |web01|
    web01.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web01.vm.hostname = "web01"
    web01.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.51"
  end

  config.vm.define "web02" do |web02|
    web02.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web02.vm.hostname = "web02"
    web02.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.11.12.52"
  end
end
```

---

Then, after running `vagrant up`, I can just `vagrant ssh lb01` I should be log-in into `lb01` VM.

Answer (score 1):

in your project directory, you have defined a `Vagrantfile`, in this Vagrantfile, you have pointed the box which needs to be used for the VM you spin, something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do
  config.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

If you want to create a new VM from the `hashicorp/precise64` box you need to have

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do
  config.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
end
```

to make sure you do not delete anything, just create a new folder and a new Vagrantfile. To spin up your new instance do

```
vagrant up --provider vmware_fusion
```